# application manifest file through mage.exe set to administrator privilege

Tags: c#, visual-studio, manifest, mage

Application using a .dll  as reference. Initially, the DLL version is 1.2.x.x version and its perfect working. When I use the updated version of dll (1.3.x.x) then it not working.

Hack: I Open my visual studio as `run as administrator` then the current version of dll(1.3.x.x) is working.

Application .net Framework: 4.5
Visual Studio: 2012

Application creates `manifest(application.exe.manifest)` through `mage.exe`.

Question:
First, Why my application requires the 'run as administrator' privilege for new dll(1.3.x.x).
Second, How to fix it.

```
<requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!--
          UAC Manifest Options
          If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
          requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

         If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward 
         compatibility th[![enter image description here][1]][1]en delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
    -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
</requestedPrivileges>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just change it to `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`, also we don't know your .dll code/files so we can't help if you don't give us enough information about the problem.